# Careers "Sort by" enhancement suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, sorting

The `sort by` functionality on at least http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/* pages could be improved in a number of ways. It could allow sorting by:

1. **Work remotely** & **Offers relocation** options
2. **Type of role** (Support, Developer - There would seem to be some categorisation obtained from employers, if the `Joel Test Score` is being made available to developer positions)
3. **Joel Test Score**
4. Reverse order of all sort by options
5. Perhaps by a results parsed list of different sets of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)
6. **Location** (alphabetically, or based on browser shared location/profile set location/GeoIP location).

I realise there is the ability to specify some of the above (including work location, and distance away from that central point), in the search pane off to the right hand side of the page, which produces a results page that exposes the ability to sort by proximity, but:

A) I can't see why the `/jobs/tag/x pages` can't have the same functionality as 'keyword' search results
-and-
B) This proximity search could also be improved by stating distance from searched "where", next to "city, state", with an linked to and/or hover-bubble map of the location or possibly travel directions from "where" to the work location c/o maps.google.com

---

P.S Is there any UX/UI tester positions on offer by StackExchange, that don't require physical presence in NY?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry! No need for a dedicated tester role. There's plenty of us that do that (including me). We are WELL aware of some of the issues with the Sort By option.

Two reasons it's the way it is. One, fixing it is way harder than you think. The way it's currently written would take a medium amount of work to redo. Second, bigger projects have taken priority.

But, not to worry, it's on the wishlist and will get fixed. Just later rather than sooner.